# How do I remove a div a second after it appears?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a background effect. On keypress it creates a div with that fades out after half a second. Every time a key is pressed, it creates a new div with a new id. How do I remove each div half a second after it was triggered?

I forgot to mention, I have a function that shortens `document.getElementById('id')` to `$('id')`. I'm not using jQuery.

Here's my code so far.

```js
function $(e) {
  return document.getElementById(e)
}

let circles = 0;
onkeypress = () => {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="effect" id="l${circles}"></div>`)
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(`l${circles}`).remove()
  },500)
  circles++
}
```

Comment: What goes wrong with the current code?

Comment: @Teemu I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null`

Comment: maybe because missing `#`? `$(`#l${circles}`).remove()`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I have a function that shortens document.getElementById('id') to $('id')

Comment: You've a closure issue, `circles` is not what you expect it to be in the delayed function.

Comment: You update circles so when the timeout runs, it is using the updated value, not the value when you added the element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use setTimeout it will use the value of counter after 500ms, that means it's no longer equal to the counter applied to create the element's id.

You should just use:

```
onkeypress = () => {
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.className = "effect";
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.body.removeChild(el);
    },500)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
onkeypress = () => {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="effect" id="l${circles}"></div>`)
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(`l${circles}`).remove()
        circles++
    }, 500)
}
```